# How to make visual changes with dynamically generated HTML code?

Tags: html, css

I generate HTML code dynamically from markdown, and wrap it into `<p></p>` tag as follows.

```
<p class="embedded_markdown">
...
<h1>...</h1>
...
<h3>...</h3>
...
</p>
```

I'd like to show some differences the generated HTML. I tried with css.

```
p.embedded_markdown {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

However, no changes is shown. 
What might be wrong? How to make some visual changes?

Comment: You shouldn't be putting heading elements in `p` tags...it's invalid HTML.

Comment: You probably have CSS rules with a higher precedence overriding this rule.

Comment: !important works wonders for me when trying to figure out a css issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you insert h1 tags inside p tags, the browser attempts to correct the markup by removing the h1 and placing it outside the p. Inspect the result using the dev tools and you will see.
Instead of `<p>` use `<div>` since divs have no symantic meaning